# Creating a Server class and Client class for a custom chatroom in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client-server, chat

**Explanation of my Program**

I have created a chat room server using Java that consists of 3 classes, a server class, a user class and a chat room class. I have also created a client class to interact with the Server. The server creates a user object every time a client connects to the server. Each user object keeps track of the chatrooms the user is in and runs a thread that listens for user input. A server object loops through each chatroom to see if it has been used in the last week.

**The Problem**

I'm wondering how to actually make a connection to my server with a client object. Currently I open two instances of eclipse. I run my server program in one, and my client program in the other, but I receive nothing in the console of either, which should happen because the server should send information to the client, which the client would then display on the console. The person on the client end could then give input that the client would take and send to the server.

I'm wondering why nothing is happening right now, and what improvements I can make.

---

**Main Files**

**Server.java**

```js
    /*
     * Creates a server that can host up to 10 clients who can join chat rooms, post messages in chatrooms, and view posts made by other clients within the same chat room
     */
    public class Server implements Runnable{
     protected ArrayList<User> userList; //A list of users, where each user is a client connected to the server
     protected LinkedList<Chatroom> chatRooms; //A list of chatrooms where each client can post messages in, where messages can be seen by all clients in the chatroom
     private ServerSocket serverSocket; //The socket for the server
     
     /*
      * Constructor for the server class. Initializes the server attributes,
      */
     public Server() {
      this.userList = new ArrayList<User>(10);
      this.chatRooms = new LinkedList<Chatroom>();
      try {
       this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
      }catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
     
     /*
      * Creates a new user when a client connects to the server, and starts a user thread
      */
     public void createUser() {
      try {
       Socket userSocket = serverSocket.accept();
       Thread user = new Thread(new User(userSocket, this));
       user.start();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
     
     /*
      * Creates a chatroom for clients to interact in
      * @param roomName: The name of the chat room to be created
      */
     protected Chatroom createChatRoom(String roomName) {
      Chatroom room = new Chatroom(roomName);
      return room;
     }
     
     /*
      * Receives messages from clients and performs actions based on the requests of the client
      * (non-Javadoc)
      * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
      */
     public void run() {
      long currentTime;
      while(true) {
       try {
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        //Loop through each chatroom and check if the chatroom has been used(joined or had a message sent to it) and remove that chatroom if it hasn't been used in a week
        for (int i = 0; i < chatRooms.size(); i++) {
         if (currentTime - 604800 >= chatRooms.get(i).dateLastUsed) {
          chatRooms.remove(i);
          //Also remove the chatroom from clients lists of chatrooms
         }
        }
        
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
     } 
     
     public static void main(String args[]) {
      Server server = new Server ();
      server.run();
     }
    }
```

**Client.java**

```js
    public class Client extends Thread{
     private String ip = "127.0.0.1";
     private int port = 5000 ;
     private Socket socket;
     private DataInputStream iStream;
     private DataOutputStream oStream;
     private String input;
     
     public Client() {
      try {
       this.socket = new Socket(ip, port);
       this.iStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
       this.oStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      }catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
     
     /*
      * Sends a message to the user
      * @param message: The message to be sent to the user
      */
     protected void send (String message) {
      try {
       oStream.writeUTF(message);
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
     
     /*
      * Closes the connection to the client
      */
     protected void close () {
      try {
       iStream.close();
       oStream.close();
       socket.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
     
     /*
      * Runs a thread for the client to constantly receive the clients input(non-Javadoc)
      * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
      */
     public void run() {
      try {
       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
       input = iStream.readUTF();
       String userInput;//Check if there is input from the user
       while (input != null) {
        input = iStream.readUTF();
        System.out.println(input);
        userInput = reader.next();
        oStream.writeUTF(userInput);
       }
       reader.close();
      }catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
     
     public static void main(String args[]) {
      Client client = new Client();
      client.run();
     }
    
    }
```

---

**Objects used by Server.java**

**User.java**

```js
    //Each user represents a client that has connected to the server
    public class User implements Runnable{
     private DataInputStream inputStream;
     private DataOutputStream outputStream;
     private Socket socket;
     private String name;
     protected LinkedList<Chatroom> chatRooms;
     private String input;
     private Server server;
     
     /*
      * User Constructor, create a user for each client connecting to the server
      * @socket The socket that the user will be communicated through
      * The client is prompted to create a name for themself, they are they prompted to do an action.
      */
     public User(Socket socket, Server server) {
      this.socket = socket;
      this.server = server;
      try {
       inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
       outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
       outputStream.writeUTF("Enter a name");
       this.name = inputStream.readUTF();
       String message = "Create a chatroom: create \nList Chat Rooms: list \n Join Chat Room: join \n Leave Chat Room: Leave";
       send(message);
      } catch (IOException e) { 
      }
     }
     
     /*
      * Returns the current amount of chatrooms this user is in
      */
     protected int chatRoomLength () {
      return this.chatRooms.size();
     }
     
     /*
      * Gets the most recent input from the user
      */
     protected String getInput() {
      return input;
     }
     
     /*
      * Puts a user/client in a chatroom
      * @param cRoom: The chatroom that the user will join 
      */
     protected void joinRoom (Chatroom cRoom) {
      chatRooms.add(cRoom);
     }
     
     /*
      * Removes a user/client from a chatroom
      */
     protected void leaveRoom (Chatroom c) {
      chatRooms.removeFirstOccurrence(c);
     }
     
     /*
      * Sends a message to the user
      * @param message: The message to be sent to the user
      */
     protected void send (String message) {
      try {
       outputStream.writeUTF(message);
      } catch (IOException e) {
      }
     }
     
     /*
      * Closes the connection to the client
      */
     protected void close () {
      try {
       inputStream.close();
       outputStream.close();
       socket.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {}
     }
     
     /*
      * Runs a thread for the client to constantly receive the clients input(non-Javadoc)
      * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
      */
     public void run() {
      try {
       input = inputStream.readUTF(); //Check if there is input from the user
       //if the user has disconnected from the server, remove them from the list
       if (input == null) {
        this.close();
        this.server.userList.remove(this);
       }else if (input.equals("create")){ //create a chat room
        this.send("Name the Chatroom");
        input = this.getInput();
        Chatroom c = this.server.createChatRoom(input);
        this.joinRoom(c);
       }else if (input.equals("list")) { //List the current chatrooms
        String rooms = "";
        for (int j = 0; j< server.chatRooms.size(); j++) {
         rooms = rooms + server.chatRooms.get(j).getName() + "\n";
        }
        this.send(rooms);
       }else if (input.equals("join")) { //Join the user to a chat room
        int end = chatRooms.size();
        if (end == 0) {
         this.send("There's currently no chat rooms");
        }else { 
         this.send("Which room would you like to join");
         input = this.getInput();
         for (int k = 0; k < end; k++) {
          if (chatRooms.get(k).getName().equals(input)) {
           Chatroom joinRoom = chatRooms.get(k);
           this.joinRoom(joinRoom);
           String message = "Chatroom " + input + " messages. \n";
           //Print the current messages in the chatroom to the user
           for (int j = 0; j < joinRoom.messages.size(); j++ ) {
            message = message + joinRoom.messages.get(j) + "\n";
           }
           this.send(message);
          } else if (k == end - 1) {
           this.send("There's no chat rooms by that name");
          }
         }
        }
       }else if (input.equals("leave")) { //Remove the user from a chatroom
        int end = this.chatRoomLength(); //if the chatroom list of the user is empty
        if (end == 0) {
         this.send("You are not in any Chat Rooms");
        }else {
         this.send("Which room would you like to leave");
         input = this.getInput();
         
         for (int m = 0; m < end; m++) { //find the chatroom by the same name
          if (this.chatRooms.get(m).getName().equals(input)) {
           this.chatRooms.remove(m);
           this.send("Great! You've been removed from" + input);
          } else if (m == end - 1) {
           this.send("You're not in a chatroom named" + input);
          }
         }
        }
       }else { //All other input is interpreted as a message to be posted in the chatrooms that the user is in
        int end = this.chatRoomLength();
        if (end == 0) {
         this.send("You can't write to any chat rooms because you are not in any");
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < end; m++) { //Add the users message to ALL the chatrooms the user is in
         Chatroom c = this.chatRooms.get(m);
         c.addMessage(input);
         //Send this added message to all the users in this chatroom
         for (int n = 0; n < c.users.size(); n++) {
          User u = c.users.get(n);
          u.send("Chatroom" + c.getName() + ":" + input);
         }
        }
       }
       
      }catch (IOException e) {
      }
     }
    }
```

**Chatroom.java**

```js
    public class Chatroom {
     private String name;  //Name of the chatroom
     protected LinkedList<String> messages; //List of text messages that have been sent by users to the chatroom and are displayed in the chatroom
     protected long dateLastUsed;  //The last time the chatroom was joined or had a message sent to it
     protected LinkedList<User> users; //The clients/users that are currently in the chatroom
     
     /*
      * Chatroom constructor
      * @param name The name of the chatroom, as determined by the user creating it
      */
     public Chatroom(String name) {
      dateLastUsed = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;  //Sent the time that the chatroom was used last to the current UNIX Epoch time
      messages = new LinkedList<String>();
      this.name = name;
     }
     
     /* 
      * Adds a message into the chatroom
      * @param message The message to be added to the chatroom
      */
     protected void addMessage(String message) {
      messages.add(message);
      dateLastUsed = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
     }
     
     /*
      * Returns the name of the chatroom
      * @return String equal to the name of the chatroom
      */
     protected String getName() {
      return this.name;
     }
     
    }
```

Comment: Is this just an exercise or are you trying to develop something for use in production? If it´s not an exercise, can you explain a bit more what are you trying to achieve? How many clients are expected and where the inputs will actually come from? There are plenty of caveats in an actual chat implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there is no call to `createUser()` which has the code to accept the socket connection.

Next is this code in `run()` function,

```
try {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            input = iStream.readUTF();
            String userInput;//Check if there is input from the user
            while (input != null) {
                input = iStream.readUTF();
                System.out.println(input);
                userInput = reader.next();
                oStream.writeUTF(userInput);
}
```

Once the socket is accepted the server prints `Enter a name` which is stored input,
inside the while loop there is another `readUTF()` call.

The problem with `readUTF()` call is that it's blocking, ie. if there isn't a `writeUTF()` call from the server it waits for data.

I solved the problem by the following snippet,

```
try {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userInput;//Check if there is input from the user
            do {
                input = iStream.readUTF();
                System.out.println(input);
                userInput = reader.next();
                oStream.writeUTF(userInput);
            } while (input != null);
            reader.close();
        }
```

Even this isn't the optimum solution as it would need Server to write something into the stream every time.

Another solution would be to read and write using different threads that way we would be able to create a full-duplex like chat, unlike this half duplex.

Then there were some NPE due to no initialization of `chatRooms` LinkedList,

Plus some logical errors like, not adding chatRooms to its List.

Wrong Code:

```
protected Chatroom createChatRoom(String roomName) {
        Chatroom room = new Chatroom(roomName);
        return room;
    }
```

Corrected Code:

```
protected Chatroom createChatRoom(String roomName) {
        Chatroom room = new Chatroom(roomName);
        this.chatRooms.add(room);
        return room;
    }
```

The best way to solve all the bugs would be Github and a few contributors :p

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by read and write using different threads? I don't know how to do this and don't really know what you are talking about

Comment: Kind of, do I always need to create a class that extends thread or implements runnable?

Comment: Yeah! Since readUTF is blocking, running it in a separate Thread would not block the Main thread. right? Likewise for writeUTF